# Rpi not catching all GPIO Inputs

Tags: python, pi-2, linux, rpi.gpio

I'm currently using a RPI2 b running linux to check for when a pulse is received from an arduino (3.3v). Something to note is that I'm also reading data from uart and writing it to a file at the same time.

On boot I start my script using screen.

I collect my uart data into a queue and then write into a file when available. Every time I receive a pulse I add a mark into a queue that is writing,when available, to the same file as the data collected from uart.

The pulse is held high for 30ms.

Below is my setup code.

```
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

def pulsed(channel):
    state.pulsequeue.put(chr(254))

GPIO.add_event_detect(17,GPIO.RISING, callback=pulsed)
```

For some reason I'm not recording every pulse all of the time. I've checked this by incrementing a variable each time I enter the pulsed loop and comparing it to  the number of times the arduino actually sends the pulse. I'm sure that the arduino is actually sending the pulse.

Is there a chance there is a problem with the duration of my pulse or am I just catching an exception where the interrupt is taking lower priority than one of the other operations happening?

Comment: How many and how often do you miss pulses?  There is nothing in your snippet to suggest a problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding a capacitor or increasing pulse duration?

Comment: @joan It depends on the run. It's usually about 1/12 I would guess sometimes less sometimes more. There really doesn't seem to be a pattern that I can recognize.

Comment: See if the pulses are picked up with http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py

Comment: @joan Trying this now thanks I'll let you know how it goes thank you.

Comment: @joan I've only tested about 5000 pulses so far but it seems to be collecting all of them with pigpiod. This is a library that you've written to control the gpio pins more effectively correct? Thanks so much for this link.

Comment: @joan one last question. Is it possible to use the serial library with pigpio? Each time I start reading from serial while using pigpio I lose input from the interrupt pin. Using the standard gpio lib I still receive all inputs.

Comment: @MathewWright I have not heard of a conflict between pigpio and serial I/O.  What do you mean by interrupt pin?  There is no interrupt pin normally associated with serial I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this exact same issue, although I do not know fully understand why the raspberry pi GPIO fails to register the rising edge on certain occasions. I took these three measures to correct for it.

1) It looks like you are doing this in Python, so I put the rising edge detection code inside its own thread.

2) I added a 1uF electrolytic on the signal line to smooth the transition, making it more likely to be registered.

3) The less elegant solution, I mirrored these connections to other GPIO pins- In your case you would need to modify your Arduino code to output this pulse on multiple lines and then connect this to the RPI.

I have a feeling it is to do with the operating system specifically the polling intervals and resource management. You could also elevate the priority of the Python program by using "renice".

Comment: Note that according to the `man`ual entry for `renice(5)`: "*Users other than the super-user may only alter the priority of processes they own, and can only monotonically increase their 'nice value' (for security reasons) within the range 0 to PRIO_MAX (20), unless a nice resource limit is set (Linux 2.6.12 and higher).  The super-user may alter the priority of any process and set the priority to any value in the range `PRIO_MIN` (-20) to `PRIO_MAX`. Useful priorities are: 20 (the affected processes will run only when nothing else in the system wants to), 0 (the 'base' scheduling ,...*"

Comment: ..."_priority) anything negative (to make things go very fast)._"  This means you **have to be root** to elevate the priority of the python or any other process.

Comment: I have never seen this problem with my pigpio Python module.

Comment: *"specifically the polling intervals..."* -> The GPIOs have actual hardware interrupts associated with them, so there is no software polling that should be going on with this in either kernel or user space.  If there is, it is a poorly written userspace library.

Comment: You can try any of the above methods and find which one works for you, I did not have time to sit there and experiment each one as I was short for time, instead I did a brute force attack. Perhaps someone can explain which is the correct solution. I have a feeling its more of a signal condition issue more than any of the other methods involving messing around with the code.

Comment: @Renegade243 I'm pretty sure gpio_add_event_detect already makes this run on a separate thread correct? Why would i need to write a thread to call another function on a thread? Please correct me If i'm not understanding this correctly. I've tried changing the length of the signal I'm sending out and it didn't help at all. I don't think it's a problem with the signal it's digital out from an Arduino so it shouldn't be noisy. I'll try renice next.

Comment: @Renegade243 I used nice to set priority to -20 and I'm still missing pulses. I've simplified my code to only contain code that writes the amount of times triggered to a file and I'm still losing about 1/12 pulses. Any ideas? I'd hate to think that the only way around this would be using multiple gpio pins.

Comment: Hey yeah in hindsight the GPIO trigger event is probably in its own thread already, as i said brute force approach of all the variables I could think of. 
Did you try using a smoothing capacitor? Thinking about it you could also try using a logic buffer between the two peripherals, this could resolve any mismatching or interference between the two devices if there is any, I don't know the exact details of your setup, so I cant say with 100% certainty. When I encountered the problem there was no obvious solution and it was absolutely critical that I did not miss a pulse and I had spare I/O.

Comment: @Renegade243 Yeah It's critical that I have them all also. I haven't tried the capacitor because I measured the signal out of the arduino with an oscilloscope and the signal was clean. How often were you sending pulses?

Comment: @joan how often are you sending your pulses?

Comment: @MathewWright The Pulse was 1pps from a GPS device, with an absolutely ridiculous rising edge time (sub ns)...  I had a feeling this was tripping up the Raspberry pi, and the only way I could change this was by "slowing" the transition using an electrolytic smoothing capacitor. It seemed to make it more reliable (factor of 5) but was still missing the occasional transitions, at this point I just mirrored the I/O. I ran out of ideas, options and time. Please try these methods let me know how it goes, I will be curious if you can find another solution.

Comment: @Renegade243 Depends what I'm testing.  Anything in the range 10-20000 µs in length at the rate of up to 200 kps.